# Laravel | Ошибка при миграции foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, миграция

Ошибка при Откате миграции 
Текст ошибки: `General error: 1832 Cannot change column 'mod': used in a foreign key constraint 'goods_mod_fk'`

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('goods', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('mod')->change();
        $table->index('mod', 'goods_mod_idx');
        $table->foreign('mod', 'goods_mod_fk')
            ->on('mods')->references('id');
    });
}
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('goods', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign('goods_mod_fk');
        $table->dropIndex('goods_mod_idx');
        $table->string('mod')->change();
    });
}
```

Вроде как мы сперва удаляет foreing key а потом меняет но, но ничего не работает. Спасибо.

Comment: у вас первой строкой смена типа столбца. Вот вам бд говорит, что не может изменит тип, потому что он связана ключом. Но если вы удалите внешний ключ, и смените тип, то не сможете заново накинуть ключ, потому что тип так требуется сменить и в справочной таблице. Соединяемые столбцы должны иметь одинаковый тип данных, иначе внешний ключ не создать.

Comment: и где у вас "сперва удаляет"? написано ж, сменить тип, создать индекс, создать внешний ключ. Про какое удаление речь?

Comment: @teran А, так вот оно что. Спасибо. И неужели в такой ситуации я не могу сделать полноценный rollback? Может есть варианты?